# Using D3.JS and the sankey plugin in a require.js module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs, splunk, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to build a requirejs module giving client code the options to render stuff with [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). The first plugin I want to use is a [sankey diagram](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/). 
My module so far:

```
define(['d3'], function(ignore) {

    console.log("bef", d3);
    require(['sankey.js']);
    console.log("aft", d3);
    d3.sankey();

    return {
        ...
        d3: d3,
        renderSankey: function(options) {
           ...
        }
    }
```

The sankey.js script uses the global `d3` variable and adds the function `sankey()`. (I tried both btw, `define(['d3'], function(ignore)` and `define(['d3'], function(d3)`, exactly the same result).
The error: `TypeError: d3.sankey is not a function`, no matter if I try to call it directly as the code shows or like `this.d3.sankey()` in the `renderSankey` function.

The console output says (both times, before and after the `require(...)` call:

```
sankey: d3.sankey()
```

[image: Screenshot FF Console]

No matter what I try, it won't work. I feel like I missed something JS specific about shadowing, but why is there a sankey function, when I `console.log` the object and a row later, when I try to call I get an error? What am I doing wrong?

info:

- I'm using this inside a splunk html dashboard, this is maybe important...
- I don't want the client code to import the dependicies (with about 100 plugins to come, this would be a pain)
- When I just copy the content of the sankey.js into my module, everything works fine

/edit: Here is the Require configuration (given by the Splunk Dashboard)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "{{SPLUNKWEB_URL_PREFIX}}/static/js",
    waitSeconds: 0 // Disable require.js load timeout
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think @Louis and I just misunderstood each other. This may be caused by my own stupidity, since I wasn't aware that a configuration of require.js can be done anywhere (and not only once in the root file). How ever, to still get the Splunk specific part I post this answer (instead of accepting Louis'):

I added a new app to my splunk environment to (a viz app). I actually configure the dependencies first (in the by other splunk apps loadable d3-viz module):

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'd3': '../app/D3_Viz/d3',         // d3.js
        'sankey': '../app/D3_Viz/sankey', // sankey.js 
        'XYZ': 'all the paths go here'
    },
    shim: {
        'sankey': ['d3'],
        'XYZ': ['d3'],
         // all the dependecies go here
    }
});

define(['splunkjs/ready!', 'jquery', 'd3'],
    function(mvc, $, ignore) {

    var d3Vis =  {
        ...
        renderSankey: function(options) {
            // load dependencies dynamically 
            require(['sankey'], function() {
                // actually render things
            });
        },
        renderXYZ: function(options) {
            require(['XYZ'], function() {
                ...
            });
        },
        ...


        }
    }
    return d3Vis;
```

All my dependencies can be configured in the viz-app (and not in the client code using the app, this has been my fundamental missunderstanding of require.js); the only thing to do is loading the app/viz as a whole (in this example in a HTML dashboard:

```
require([
    "splunkjs/mvc",
    "splunkjs/mvc/utils",
    "splunkjs/mvc/tokenutils",
    "underscore",
    "jquery",
    "splunkjs/mvc/simplexml",
    "splunkjs/mvc/headerview",
    "splunkjs/mvc/footerview",
    ...
    "../app/D3_Viz/viz"
    ],
    function(
        mvc,
        utils,
        TokenUtils,
        _,
        $,
        DashboardController,
        HeaderView,
        FooterView,
        ...
        d3Viz
    ){
        ... splunk specific stuff
        // No dependencies have to be configured 
        // in the client code
        d3Viz.renderSankey({...});
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require` call you are using to load `sankey` is asynchronous. It will launch the loading of `sankey` but by the time `require` returns, `sankey` is not loaded. You should change your code to:

```
define(['d3', 'sankey'], function (d3) {
    d3.sankey();
```

I take it that `d3` also leaks the symbol `d3` in the global space but AMD modules should not rely on global symbols unless these are part of the runtime environment (e.g. `window`, `document`).

You also need to set your RequireJS configuration to make `sankey` dependent on `d3` because the `define` above does not *by itself* ensure that `d3` will load before `sankey`. So you need this in your configuration:

```
shim: {
    sankey: ['d3']
}
```

This makes `sankey` dependent on `d3`. (Note that [`shim`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) can only be used to affect the loading of files that are not proper AMD module. `sankey` does not call `define` to register itself, and thus is not a proper AMD module, and we can use `shim` for it.)

Also, module names should generally not have `.js` in them so when you want to load the plugin, load it as `sankey`, not `sankey.js`.

Comment: That was my very first approach. The problem is, that sankey needs d3 to be finished (I know, thats not good at all, but it's not my module and I have to use it as it is). So this approach will only work *sometimes*. Most times an error occurs.

Comment: Please add your RequireJS configuration to your question. I'm sure there is a fix.

Comment: added the configuration - and an info at the end: When I just copy everything from the sankey.js into the module, everything works fine

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution to the dependency issue.

Comment: It *works*, but is unfortunately no solution for me, because:
1. Client code needs knowledge about module dependencies, that's verys bad style(see info), 2. I will have up to 100 modules depending on d3, configuring those dependencies in every page using it is error prone and bad style. There must be a better solution.... but htank you anyway!

Comment: It's a matter of what RequireJS needs you to do to use it, not a matter of style. After the edits you made and the comment you have here, your questions sounds like "I want to use RequireJS, but not really." See, RequireJS **requires** that you specify the dependencies between the modules you load (be they real AMD modules or non-modularized scripts that are `shim`ed) because that's how you ensure correct loading. If you do not want to specify the dependencies, then you are effectively saying "I don't want to use RequireJS."

Comment: You are absolutely right; I actually *have* to use RequireJS (since its part of the SplunkJS stack) while the third party modules I *have* to use are not made for RequireJS